# How to get clicked element in Backbone Marrionette ui click

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, marionette

```
        ui: {
        "feature": "a.mouse-event-f"
    },

    events: {
        "click @ui.feature": "select"
    },

    select: function() {
        this.ui.feature.find("div.item_number").addClass("item_number_green");
    },
```

There are several  elements with class "mouse-event-f" and in my case the class "item_number_green" is being added to all of them. But I need to add this class only to the clicked element. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `select` function is passed an event parameter containing the target of the click event. You can use that parameter like this:

```
select: function( e ) {
    $(e.target).addClass("item_number_green");
},
```